# Insert javascript buttons inside form but not send form on Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

hmm, i dont know how to explain this properly but i'll do my best.
I got a PHP form that has many fields. One of them is a textarea that i hold some php values in there. I wanted to install a beautifier to show the php values with a nice css style.
The whole thing works fine...but the beautifier has some javascript buttons that go with it to Toggle on/off styles in the textarea. Now this textarea is inside a **form** so when i click the buttons the form gets submitted. Although the buttons are only javascript changes...
The buttons are like this:

```
<p>
<button class="actions" onclick="settings.toggleEditor()">turn on/off CodePress</button>
<button class="actions" onclick="settings.toggleLineNumbers()">show/hide line numbers</button>
<button class="actions" onclick="settings.toggleAutoComplete()">turn on/off auto-complete</button>
<button class="actions" onclick="settings.toggleReadOnly()">turn on/off read only</button>
</p>
```

If i add the buttons outside the form, of course they work fine....but the end of the form tag is far and i have to scroll down to Toggle them.

My question: How can i add the buttons under my textarea but NOT execute the form when clicked ? Just let them do their thing to the textarea.
-Thanks

Comment: give your buttons `type="button"`

Comment: quick/dirty: `onclick="settings.foo(); return false;"` to disable the automatic submit action.

Comment: this worked but you didnt provide an answer to vote it +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a button button instead of a submit button (which is the default).

```
<button type="button" ...>
```

Comment: yeah sorry, i was wrong before...it works but not in explorer. still trying to figure out why not.
If i move the buttons outside the form, they work in Explorer as well.

Comment: well it works for Mozilla and thats fine by me :) who uses explorer anymore ? hehe 
_Thanks